# How can I add number to getMonth() + 1, it is getting added as string

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, get

when I do new Date().getMonth()+ 1 it gives 111 instead os december ie 12. I know that it's indexed from 0 but I can't figure out how to add 1 to it.

```
client.on('friendMessage', (friend, message) => {
    fs.writeFile("./ChatLogs/UserLogs/" + friend.getSteamID64() + "-log-" + new Date().getDate() + "-" + new Date().getMonth()+ 1 + "-" + new Date().getFullYear() + ".json", JSON.stringify({ logs: userLogs[friend.getSteamID64()] }), (ERR) => {
        if (ERR) {
            console.log("## An error occurred while writing UserLogs file: " + ERR);
        }
    });
    chatLogs += friend.getSteamID64() + " : " + message + "\n";
    fs.writeFile("./ChatLogs/FullLogs/log-" + new Date().getDate() + "-" + new Date().getMonth()+ 1 + "-" + new Date().getFullYear() + ".txt", chatLogs, (ERR) => {
        if (ERR) {
            console.log("## An error occurred while writing FullLogs file: " + ERR);
        }
    });
}):;
```

Comment: convert month from string to number, then add 1

Answer (score 3):

This situation happens because `"-" + new Date().getMonth()` is a concatenation of strings (months are converted to a string). So when you add 1, it just again converts it to a string, and concatenate. Just put a parentheses, to make it operate on two numbers.

`"-" + (new Date().getMonth()+ 1) + "-"`